# Outlook compatible instant messaging application

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to develop a software that is compatible with Outlook and that will provide presence and IM infrastructure to Outlook like MSN Messenger / Communicator etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be possbile with Outlook 2007 and Exchange Server.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/use-instant-messaging-services-with-outlook-HP001233551.aspx

Comment: This article mentions known IM services. What I want to know is, is it possible to develop an IM service like these?

Comment: In general it should be possible. It's going to depend on your requirements.

Comment: Have a look at Visual Studio Tools for Office VSTO.  See if has what you looking for.

Comment: I think it involves lots of server side coding than client side. IM presence servers, IM servers. Lots of work is needed.